How to use ONNX exported from yolov8 model files on Python
I exported an model in onxx format from YOLOV8 but when i run the inference doesn't work
!yolo export model="/content/runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt" format=onnx imgsz=[640,480]

My question is how can i reproduce the same bouding box of YOLOV8 on the onxx format ?
Thanks

What do you mean by "inference doesn't work" and what is your inference running code?

I use https://github.com/sstainba/Yolov8.Net for inference
see the documentation.... export must be done with --Opset=15 flag
I do not use python though... CLI works best for me ito exports
YMMV, but this specific Library works like a charm
